# Making a field required, only when some numbers entered, the max number of numbers will be 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I have a text field. It is optional. If at all, some thing entered in the text box, then only the validations should take place. It has to check for the number of numbers should be less than 10.

I wrote something like this

```
<div>@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.ProviderMembers[index].ProviderID, new { @class = "input-small", maxlength = "10", data_mask = "9999999999", placeholder = "ID#" })</div>
```

There is a Next button is there. Once the Next button is clicked, This text box needs to be validated. If nothing is entered, it should go to the next page. If at all anything is entered, then only it has to validate for numbers and number of numbers = 10

```
this.RuleFor(model => model.newProviderID).NotEmpty().When(model => string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.newProviderID)).WithContentMessage(Resources.Model.MemberInformation, Resources.Validation.IDRequired);
```

Comment: `maxlength="10"` will limit it to 10 characters or less, where you needing additional validation done, like insuring it is all numbers?

Comment: Are you using standard MVC attributes to control the validations? For example, have you applied the `[Required]` attribute to this field?

Comment: Originally you had an input field, but now you are using a Textarea, an input field seems more appropriate. Where you specifically wanting a Textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you appear to be using HTML as you have `data-attributes` why not use the new input types.

**Input Type: number**

> The number type is used for input fields that should contain a numeric
>   value.

You can also set restrictions on what numbers are accepted:

**Example**

Define a numeric field (with restrictions):

```
<input type="number" class="input-small" data-mask="9999999999" id="ProviderMembers_0__ProviderID" min="0" max="10" name="ProviderMembers[0].ProviderID" placeholder="ID#" type="text" value="">
```